# Re-direct old URL ( php?id=123 ) to rewrited URL

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite my old url ( look like that product_detail.php?cat_id=9&id=351 ) to new rewrite url.

But when the visitor go to my site, they can visit by both old and new URL.
How can I make all visitor are redirected to new URL ?

In example :
mydomain.com/product_detail.php?cat_id=9&id=351 => mydomain.com/product/product-name-1.html

This is my .htaccess content.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ index.php
RewriteRule ^phong-trung-bay.html$ showroom.php

RewriteRule ^san-pham.html$ product.php

RewriteRule ^danh-sach-cong-trinh.html$ project_cat.php
RewriteRule ^cac-cong-trinh-(.*)-([0-9]*\.?[0-9]).html$ project.php?id=$2
RewriteRule ^cong-trinh-(.*)-([0-9]*\.?[0-9]).html$ project_detail.php?id=$2
</IfModule>
```

The problem is the visitor can visit old URL and also new URL. So I will have 2 URL per content.

Comment: What's the content of your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: how is the cat_id and the id reflected in the new url? has the 1 in product-name-1.html a special meaning?

Comment: I just add the content of my .htaccess to the question.
So, my product url will transform from :
product_detail.php?cat_id=9&id=351

to : 
san-pham-luxury-9-351.html
Hope you can give me some advices.

Comment: htaccess cannot translate id to a product slug by querying your database.

Answer (score 0):

Since you use a php function to create your target url file name, you cannot use `.htaccess` Rewrite Engine. Instead you have to redirect via PHP:

Create `product_detail.php`, or if it still exists, put this code at the beginning:

```
$newUrl = '/product/' . createSlugFunction();
header("Location: ".$newUrl,TRUE,301);
exit();
```

While `createSlugFunction()` represents your function that creates the slug.

Comment: Thank you so much ! But new URL will content the name of product (slug), look like
mydomain.com/product/villa-gate-luxury-1.html

My .htaccess can completely remove cat_id and id from old URL but cannot add new slug.

Comment: and how do you create your slug?

Comment: From now, I am using a PHP code, to transform product name become a slug. There is still not any slug in Database.

Comment: Thank you so muc, Mario A. But this link make me stuck in a loop.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Can you be more precise please?

Comment: If I combine this code with .htaccess( all content above ), this URL will stuck in loop. 
PHP send header to newURL, then .htaccess rewrite to new URL ... and to be continued.
But if I remove .htaccess, server will response 404 error.

Comment: No wonder, in your php you redirect to `cong-trinh-...` and in your `.htaccess` you redirect from `cong-trinh-...` back to `project_detail.php`. Please remove the  `RewriteRule ^cong-trinh-...` from your `.htaccess`

Comment: Thanks you Mario A.
But if I remove the rewrite code in .htaccess, I will recieve 404 error.
But many thanks for your help !